# Flutter/Dart how to combine elements by attribute inside a list and make operations over them

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of objects like this:

```
[
    {"name": 'olive oil', "quantity": "1", "unit": "spoons"},
    {"name": 'olive oil', "quantity": "2", "unit": "spoons"},
    {"name": 'parmesan cheese', "quantity": "20", "unit": "slices"},
    {"name": 'parmesan cheese', "quantity": "3/4", "unit": "cup"},
    {"name": 'salt', "quantity": "1", "unit": "teaspoon"},
];
```

And I would like to get something like this:

```
    {"name": 'olive oil', "total": "3 spoons"},
    {"name": 'parmesan cheese', "total": "20 slices + 3/4 cup"},
    {"name": 'salt', "total": "1 teaspoon"},
```

Where elements with the same name were merged and its units and quantities were added in a new attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
void main() {
List<Map<String,String>> data=[
    {"name": 'olive oil', "quantity": "1", "unit": "spoons"},
    {"name": 'olive oil', "quantity": "2", "unit": "spoons"},
    {"name": 'parmesan cheese', "quantity": "20", "unit": "slices"},
    {"name": 'parmesan cheese', "quantity": "3/4", "unit": "cup"},
    {"name": 'salt', "quantity": "1", "unit": "teaspoon"},
];

  for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    data[i]['quantity']=data[i]['quantity'].toString()+' '+data[i]['unit'].toString();
  print(data[i]);
  }

}
```

it will give you the output like this

```
{name: olive oil, quantity: 1 spoons, unit: spoons}
{name: olive oil, quantity: 2 spoons, unit: spoons}
{name: parmesan cheese, quantity: 20 slices, unit: slices}
{name: parmesan cheese, quantity: 3/4 cup, unit: cup}
{name: salt, quantity: 1 teaspoon, unit: teaspoon}
```

Now you can Use Quantity anywhere